# Understanding assembly generated by C function call

Tags: c, assembly

```
        .file   "calc.c"
        .text
.globl calc
        .type   calc, @function
calc:
        pushl   %ebp     
        movl    %esp, %ebp 
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx
        movl    16(%ebp), %ecx  
        leal    (%edx,%edx,2), %edx 
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax 
        leal    (%edx,%eax,2), %eax
        movl    %ecx, %edx
        sall    $4, %edx
        subl    %ecx, %edx
        addl    %edx, %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .size   calc, .-calc
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I'm trying to understand what's going on with this assembly code.  I created it by typing `gcc -O1 -S calc.c` which generated a `calc.s` assembly file.

Can someone explain (in terms of the addition and multiplication in `calc.c`) what is going on, line by line?

The original C code is:

```
int calc(int x, int y, int z)
{
        return 3*x + 2*y + 15*z;
}
```

Comment: You have created an unused nested function which has been optimized out so it is not in the assembly listing. Delete the `main` function and try again.

Comment: Probably you have a typo `.global calc`

Comment: Sorry.  I corrected the code.  (assembly and c)

Comment: Please improve the title so it will be useful to future visitors to the site. The current title is so vague that somebody with the same question will not realize that this is the same question. Also, this does not appear to be a specific programming problem. What is the programming problem you're having where understanding this calc function is the solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, now it does something, I'll annotate it for you

```
calc:
    pushl   %ebp           ; \
    movl    %esp, %ebp     ; /  set up basic stack frame
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx  ; load x
    movl    16(%ebp), %ecx ; load z
    leal    (%edx,%edx,2), %edx ; calculate x + 2 * x
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax ; load y
    leal    (%edx,%eax,2), %eax ; calculate (x + 2 * x) + (2 * y)
    movl    %ecx, %edx     ; make a temp copy of z
    sall    $4, %edx       ; calculate z * 16
    subl    %ecx, %edx     ; calculate (z * 16) - z
    addl    %edx, %eax     ; calculate final sum
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Thank you @harold.  How do you know that x, y and z are being loaded?  I don't understand how to tell just by `8` `16` and `12` that those variables are being referenced.

Comment: Excellent answer! Some additional information: C pushes function arguments onto the stack in reverse order, and `int`s are 4 bytes long.

Comment: I cheated a bit and inferred their meaning from what's being done with them. You could also look up the `cdecl` calling convention and see which argument-index they have based on the offset.

Comment: `leal(x,y,z), w` translates to `w = x + y * z`  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax

Comment: Astonishing how `16z-z` is preferred over `15z`. Awesome question AND answer!

Comment: Shifting and adding/subtracting are very "cheap" operations, while multiplication is "expensive" in terms of processing time. Shifting a number to the left is equivalent to multiplying by 2, and modern compilers are optimized to handle common operations efficiently. For example, you'll find that `10x` may be converted to `2x + 8x`, which is implemented as `x<<1 + x<<3`.

Comment: @harold can you explain how `sall    $4, %edx ` means to multiply z by 16?  What does the `$4` mean? And, what is `sall`?

Comment: @JohnSmith `sall` is the `l` ("long", 4 bytes, `dword`) version of `sal` (shift arithmetic left) which is a synonym of `shl` (shift left). $4 means 4. So it's like `z << 4`.

Comment: @harold if we were using 16-bit registers, e.g. `%ed` instead of `%edx` would the commnand be `sal` instead?

Comment: @JohnSmith it's called `%dx` actually, and it would be `salw` (`w` for `word`)

Comment: @harold: well, "called"... According to the inventor of this assembly language, the instruction is called "SHL", and the register is "EDX" (originally, "DX") -- and when googling, you ought to use the *regular* name. This is gas style assembly, which (IIRC) originally was for another type of processor with its own typical syntax.

Comment: @Jongware `dx`, `%dx`, who cares. Point is, it's not `ed`.

Comment: @harold: of course -- only meant to point out gas assembler syntax is the odd duck here, in case the OP would want to google for more info.